# jQuery append not in DOM and script run twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
          $("li").on("click", "span",function(){
              if ( $(this).attr('class') == "plus" ){
               var _this = $(this);
               var parent = $(this).parent();
               parent.append($("<select class='aruCikk'>").html("<option hidden disabled selected value> -- Válassz egy opciót! -- </option>"));
                  var liSelect = $(_this).parent();
                  var aruAdatokId = _this.parent().parent().parent().attr('class');
                  var params = {mode:"aruadatok", id:aruAdatokId};
                  $.post("./src/source.php", params, function(result, success, xhr){
                      if( success == "success" ){
                          var select = $("select");
                          $.each(result, function(key, value){
    
                           var net_price = value["netUnitPrice"] * value["quantity"];
                                    var vat_amount = calcVat(net_price, value["vatRate"]);
                                    var gross_amount = net_price + vat_amount;
                              
                              $(liSelect).find(select).append($("<option class='"+value["aruAdatokId"]+" "+value["quantity"]+" "+value["quantityUnit"]+"'>").html(value["productName"]+", "+net_price+" (nettó) + "+vat_amount+" (áfakulcs: "+value["vatRate"]+") = "+gross_amount+" "+value['Currency']));
                              });
                          $(liSelect).find(select).parent().append($("<input type='text' name='quantity' class='quantity' size=1>").html("<span class='quantityUnit'></span>"));
                      }
                      }, 'json');
                  _this.removeClass('plus').addClass('minus');
                  _this.find('img').attr('src', './images/minus.png');
                  _this.find('img').attr('alt', 'minus');
    
                  var grandParent = $(this).parent().parent()
                  grandParent.append($("<li>").html("<span class='plus'><img src='./images/plus.png' alt='plus'></span>"));
              } else if ( $(this).attr('class') == "minus" ){
               $(this).parent().remove();
              }
          });

             $("select").on('change', function(){
                 var selected = $( "option:selected", this );
                 var params = selected.attr("class");
                });
      });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta content = "text/html; CHARSET=UTF-8" >
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="elonezet">
  <ol>
   <li style="background-color:#EEEEEE" class="37">
                <p><strong>XYZ Kft.</strong>, Address Etc. datas<br>
     Kelt: 2019.10.28., teljesítés: 2019.10.28.
                </p>
    <ul>
     <li class="65">
      <span class="minus"><img src="./images/minus.png" alt="minus"></span>
      <select>
       <option>Option 1</option>
       <option>Option 2</option>
       <option selected="" value="">Option 3</option>
       <option>Option 4</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" name="quantity" class="quantity" value="1" size="1">
      <span class="quantityUnit">db</span></li><li><span class="plus"><img src="./images/plus.png" alt="plus"></span>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ol>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's not a complete example, I use database for select/options elements in new lists.
When it generate a new list, I couldn't detect change of select elements. And if I click on the "plus" picture, the script run twice, firstly run the "if" part, after run the "else" part of code.

Comment: It looks like the code in the snippet would work as intended, it doesn't remove elements when clicking "plus".

Comment: Yes, it's true, and very irritating, I couldn't repeat the bug in snippet. But in the real environtment it's a big problem. :/

Comment: Check for any redundancy on your project, specially jquery scripts and files.

Comment: Well, we can't help, if we can't reproduce the problem. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for some tips of how you can create an example reproducing the issue. Probably you'll find the issue while creating the example, but that is not a bad option either.

Comment: Oh, I checked it again. It's reproduce the bug. If you run the snippet, on the first click on "plus" seems it doesn't work. But in background it replace for the new element. First time the script change the class for "minus", and add a new element with "plus". After it running again, and remove the clicked element, which is now a "minus", And you just see the last "plus" element,
And the further clicking not remove autmatically, and I couldn't detect changing in the Select.

Comment: Now had some time to get into this. You've delegated the click event to the `span`s inside the `li` elements. However, there's a nested `ul` element inside the first `li` of the `ol`. The inner `span` is also inside the outer `li`, and the click handler is executed twice, at first from the inner, and then from the outer `li`. Fix the issue by delegating to `ul span`, or adding the event object parameter (`e`) to the handler's argument list and then prevent the propagation of the event (`e.stopPropagation();`);